# fetch http request succeeds in Chrome and Firefox but fails in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, fetch

If we run the following code in safari it fails saying "failed to load resource: cannot parse response"

```
fetch('https://mycompanyname/service/contracts-api/operatingMode', {
  method: "GET",
  headers: new Headers({
    'Authorization': 'Basic VGVzdFVzZXIxOlRFU1QhdXNlcjE=',
    'X-mycompanyname-ContractsServer': 'someurl'
  })
}
```

[image: safari inspect element preview]

[image: safari inspect element headers]
But if we run the same code in Chrome or Firefox, it succeeds (in the same mac computer).

Is there any quirk in Safari fetch request that I am not considering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed the issue adding in apache the following line:

```
Header unset Upgrade
```

The explanation is here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/937253/https-doesnt-work-with-safari